# Pass nested Ansible vars into playbook inventory file

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I am wondering is it possible to pass in the `--extra-vars` when running an ansible-playbook in order to inject the variables into an inventory file, which I am using to run my playbook.

*sample playbook*

```
- name: "Create CI pipeline"
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: "Create PreCodeReview jobs"
    tags:
      - jenkins
      - jenkins-jobs
    when: jenkins is defined
    local_action:
      module: jenkins_job
      url: "{{ jenkins.url }}"
      user: "{{ jenkins.username }}"
      token: "{{ jenkins.access_token }}"
      name: "{{ jenkins.component.name }}_PreCodeReview"
      config: "{{ lookup('template', '../templates/jenkins/add-pre-code-config.xml') }}"

  - name: "Create Release jobs"
    tags:
      - jenkins
      - jenkins-jobs
    when: jenkins is defined
    local_action:
      module: jenkins_job
      url: "{{ jenkins.url }}"
      user: "{{ jenkins.username }}"
      token: "{{ jenkins.access_token }}"
      name: "{{ jenkins.component.name }}_Release"
      config: "{{ lookup('template', '../templates/jenkins/add-release-config.xml') }}"
```

I am looking to pass in **`jenkins.component.name`** at run time, I have attempted this with the following `jenkins.component.name=<name>` and `"{'jenkins':{'component':{'name':<name>}}}"`

This didn't work.

Here is the inventory I am using to run the playbook

*sample inventory*

```
all:
  hosts:
    local:
      ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_connection: local
      project_name: magic_proj
      jenkins:
        url: https://my/jenkins
        username: admin
        access_token: f96hjfg54354b3e8512d491fb471fd
        keep_builds: 20
        components:
          - name: <repo_name>
            repository: <repo_url>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking to pass in `jenkins.component.name` at run time, I have attempted this with the following `jenkins.component.name=<name>` and `"{'jenkins':{'component':{'name':<name>}}}"`

You were very close: the `--extra-vars` wants either `key=value` pairs, JSON, YAML, or `@./some/file`, [as specified in the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line)

Regrettably, what you provided was *Python* syntax, and not *JSON* syntax; if you change your command line to `--extra-vars '{"jenkins":{"component":{"name":<name>}}}'`

*update:*
However, even that has a problem: it appears that for `dict` structures, ansible does not **merge** inventory `dict`s and `extra-var` `dict`s, so you will need to either choose a "flat" `extra-var` name (such as *almost* what you also attempted: `--extra-vars '{"jenkins_component_name": ""}'`) or manually merge the structures together in your playbook (perhaps via `pre_tasks:` or similar)